# Extending wifi and Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wifi-configuration

Hi just wondering if anyone can help. I own a house and we have a barn conversion outside and need to get internet into the barn but the power line split when comes into the property so they don't run through the same fuse box. So does anyone know how I can get internet out there. It's not far from the property but the wifi is not good out there and need to plug the CCTV system into the Internet hope someone can help 
Thanks matt

Comment: You could get someone to run an underground cable. OSP (Outside Plant) cabling has many dangers, so this is really not something that you should do yourself. Lightning, grounding, bonding, frost line, ground heaves, etc. all can cause serious, even life threatening, problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called a "Point-to-Point" wi-fi system. These are designed for exactly your case - where you want to extend wi-fi to another building. These use one system on each end with an external antenna. Typically the antennas are high-gain, but if the distance between buildings is reasonable short, this would be overkill. Just search for this -- there are many, many vendors. Another option is to use a high-gain antenna on the barn with an wi-fi extender. Wilson Electronics and others make these. A third option is to use a fiber optic link between the two buildings. Using a fiber optic link eliminates concerns about potential electrical problems. Even a good ground rod at each side does not guarantee a good mutual ground between two buildings on two different electrical systems, and you don't want to fry your network.  Ron was very correct about the potential problems with OSP cabling, but these do not apply to fiber optic systems.